# Continuous variable vs. Nominal variables

Tags: r, spss, binary-data

I have a file with a continuous variable Y, and a set of 20 binary variables (yes/no). I wish to do the following two tasks:

1. To find which of the 20 variables are related to the variable Y, i.e., which values of "yes" are related to high scores of Y.
2. To find if there are "subgroups" among the 20 variables (i.e., if for example variables 1, 3 and 7 are related).

Which method should I use, and if you can, how do I perform this in either R or SPSS ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Was my answer below useful? If so, would you mind accepting/upvoting it? If not, let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the binary fields such that YES is encoded as 1 and NO as 0. In other words, convert them from character to numeric form.
2. In order to identify variables that are correlate with Y, perform a **correlation test** between each variable and Y. Variables that have a *positive* correlation coefficient with a *significant* p-value, are the ones that you're looking for. (i.e., These are the variables for which "yes" values are related to high scores of Y.) Here's how you can do this in SPSS: http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-correlation-test/ (You can skip to step 2: Assumptions Correlation Test)
3. To identify groups of variables based on their correlation with each other, you can perform **cluster analysis** on the variables themselves. 
   Refer to 'Clustering Variables' section on page #371 in the following document: http://www.norusis.com/pdf/SPC_v13.pdf